# Get Users Appointment details using javascript onload in CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there anyway to particular crm users appointment details using javascript ODATA or is there any other way.

Thanks
Vishnu

Comment: Could you please be more explanatory. Your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Rest JavaScript SDK to do so.

```
var retrieveAppointmentsCallBack = function(results){
    for(var i = 0;i<results.length;i++){
        var appointment = results[i];
        //do something
    }
}

var options = "$filter=OwnerId\Id eq guid'" + userId + "'";
SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("AppointmentSet", options, retrieveAppointmentsCallBack, function (error) { alert(error.message); }, appointmentsRetrieveComplete);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. so what i need to do, need to pass guid of user as userId. thats it?

Comment: from where can i get the success results